# how to create own listener for class with two swing components

Tags: swing, awt

I have class named MyComponent with two swing components.
[I want to get like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiCvn.png)

Is it possible?

Comment: *"I want to get like that."* Post the text, not an image of it!

Comment: What is this 'listener' supposed to listen to? What should it do when it hears something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your Listener. You may have to modify your component to add Listener.

```
public interface MyListener {
    void getSelectedItem();
}
```

your component would be like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyComponent {
    JTextField txtField;
    JList<String> list;
    List<MyListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MyListener>();

    public void  addListener(MyListener listener ){
        this.listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void  removeListener(MyListener listener ){
        this.listeners.remove(listener);
    }

}
```

When to invoke the listener, What to listen all depends on your component.

Comment: Your custom listener should extend EventListener

Comment: @FredK The depends on what he want to listen :-)

Comment: Beniton. Thanks you so much. It is what I want. :-)